# Why does my relay have the HSDir flag when I don't host any hidden services?

Tags: onion-services

i think hidden services are the dark nets inside the TOR network. I am not hosting any web servers. Then how my OR is flagged as HSDir?

Answer (score 3):

[Hidden service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html) directories are not required to host hidden services themselves (this would be a security concern; greatly reducing the number of possible locations a hidden service could be hosted). Having the `HSDir` flag indicates that your router is configured to host hidden service descriptors (which other Tor relays use to find out about hidden services and connect to them) and has been up for at least 24 hours.

More information about the `HSDir` flag can be found in the [Rendezvous Specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/plain/rend-spec.txt).

Comment: This requirement has since been updated such that, to be eligible for the HSDir flag, you must have both the "fast" and "stable" flags.